# ¿Por qué usando SSE2 no se acelera la ejecución de mi código?

Tags: c, coma-flotante, double

Este programa en C trata ver la aceleración de código al ejecutralo con variables normales frente a ejecutarlo con instrucciones SSE2. En concreto comparo la multiplicación de dos números. En el caso de usar SSE2 se pueden multiplicar de cuatro en cuatro. Los números los obtengo de una función rand y los guardo en un array.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double valores [32];
    double a = 9999999.9;
    srand ((unsigned int) time (NULL));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        valores [i] = ((double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
        //printf("valor[%d]: %f\n", i, valores[i]);
    }
    opFlotante(valores);
    opFlotanteSSE(valores);

    return 0;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void opFlotante(double valores [32]) {
    int i, numVeces;
    double valor1, valor2, resultado;

    struct timespec start, finish;
    float elapsed;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    for (numVeces = 0; numVeces < 10000000; numVeces++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 31; i += 2) {
            valor1 = valores[i];
            valor2 = valores[i+1];
            resultado = valor1 * valor2;
        }
    } 

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
    elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("Tiempo transcurrido sin SSE: %f segundos\n", elapsed);

}

void opFlotanteSSE(double valores [32]) {
    struct timespec start, finish;
    float elapsed;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    __m128d A, B, res;
    int i, numVeces;
    for (numVeces = 0; numVeces < 10000000; numVeces++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 31; i+=8) {
            A = _mm_set_pd(valores[i], valores[i+1]);
            B = _mm_set_pd(valores[i+2], valores[i+3]);
            res = _mm_mul_pd(A,B);
        }
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
    elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("Tiempo transcurrido con SSE: %f segundos", elapsed);


}
```

Comment: Deberias incluir el resultado que obtienes, y en qué plataforma (compilador, seteos) estás trabajando, Por otro lado (y aunque esto te juega en contra) en `for (i = 0; i < 31; i+=8)` no debería incrementarse de a `4` ?

Comment: Efectivamente, el incremento tiene que ser de 4! Pues el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente: sin SSE 0.422068 segundos y con SSE 0.505005 segundos. Tarda aún más, algo tiene que estar mal. Estoy usando como IDE NetBeans 8.2, como opciones de compilador tengo -msse2.

Comment: Por lo que yo entiendo, tendría que realizarse cuatro veces más rápido con SSE.